# Consulta MYSQL PHP trazer resultados de Hoje e Essa Semana

Tags: php, mysql, select, data

Eu estou montando tipo um CRM, onde faz as consultas no MYSQL com PHP para trazer os compromissos que tenho hoje, essa semana e todos outros.

Gostaria que trouxesse algo assim:

```
Hoje:
compromisso A
compromisso B

Essa semana:
compromisso C

Todos
compromisso D
compromisso E
```

A tabela no MYSQL está assim:

```
compromissos
id|datacompromisso    |compromisso
1 |2018-07-30 10:00:00|compromisso A
2 |2018-07-30 10:00:00|compromisso B
3 |2018-07-31 10:00:00|compromisso C
4 |2018-08-10 10:00:00|compromisso D
5 |2018-09-20 10:00:00|compromisso E
```

Tem como trazer tudo na mesma consulta, ou tenho que separar em 3 consultas (Consulta de hoje, consulta dessa semana e todo outros)

Os resultados no PHP estão assim:

```
foreach($results as $r){
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$r->datacompromisso.'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$r->compromisso.'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$r->grupo.'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Caro Leonardo, não coloque o código de uma resposta na pergunta, somos PERGUNTAS e RESPOSTAS, se ainda tem algum problema com o código de alguma pergunta comente para quem respondeu, se editar adicionando o código na pergunta vai parecer que a resposta dele não tem sentido algum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode adicionar uma coluna no seu `SQL` que indique isso a partir de algumas verificações de datas com `IF`, segue um exemplo:

```
SELECT IF(
    DATE(datacompromisso) = DATE(NOW()),
    'hoje',
    IF(
        YEAR(datacompromisso) = YEAR(NOW()) AND WEEK(datacompromisso) = WEEK(NOW()),
        'semana',
        'todos'
    )
) AS grupo
```

Depois disso você trata na programação, as linhas que tiverem `hoje` significa que pertence ao grupo de hoje. As que tiverem `semana` pertencem à semana atual. E por fim as que tiverem `todos` não pertencem a nenhum dos grupos anteriores.

Você pode fazer essa separação em `array`, por exemplo:

```
$hoje = array();
$semana = array();
$todos = array();

foreach($results as $r){
  if ($r->grupo == "hoje")
    array_push($hoje, $r);
  else if ($r->grupo == "semana")
    array_push($semana, $r);
  else if ($r->grupo == "todos")
    array_push($todos, $r);
}
```

Neste ponto você já terá todas as tarefas separadas de acordo com o grupo, agora é só fazer um `foreach` em cada grupo e imprimir na tela para o usuário:

```
<h3>Compromissos de Hoje</h3>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Compromisso</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    foreach($hoje as $h){
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '  <td>'.$h->datacompromisso.'</td>';
      echo '  <td>'.$h->compromisso.'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
    }
  </tbody>
</table>

<h3>Compromissos desta Semana</h3>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Compromisso</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    foreach($semana as $s){
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '  <td>'.$s->datacompromisso.'</td>';
      echo '  <td>'.$s->compromisso.'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
    }
  </tbody>
</table>

<h3>Outros Compromissos</h3>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Compromisso</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    foreach($todos as $t){
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '  <td>'.$t->datacompromisso.'</td>';
      echo '  <td>'.$t->compromisso.'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: legal, a consulta deu certinho, mas como faço para separar o hoje da semana e de todos os outros na hora que for trazer o resultado no php? estou usando o foreach($comrpomissos as $comp){echo '<tr><td>'.$comp->compromisso.'</td></tr>}

Comment: Você pode separar em `arrays` antes e depois fazer um `foreach` para cada grupo

Comment: Ou se você apenas der um `GROUP BY datacompromisso` ele já vai trazer na ordem certa.

Comment: não entendi a parte dos array, como faria isso?

Comment: Coloque seu código `PHP` para que eu possa dar um exemplo em cima dele.

Comment: alterei la a resposta

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo alterei minha resposta.

Comment: o foreach em cada grupo seria isso? foreach($hoje as $h){ echo $h->datacompromisso;}

Comment: Exatamente, ai você faz uma tabela para cada grupo.

Comment: editei a resposta como deixei, devo estar fazenod algo errado, a consulta está aparecendo em branco

Comment: Você não quer imprimir o grupo `hoje` em uma tabela, o `semana` em outra e o `todos` em outra?

Comment: sim, vdd, coloquei linha, mas mesmo assim, não deveria mostrar os valores?

Comment: Veja se da forma que coloquei resolve. Caso não, coloque o código onde você executa o `select`.

Comment: alterei a pergunta

Comment: Na minha resposta eu adicionei o código para imprimir as tabelas, você colocou ele após a separação dos grupos?

Comment: O `foreach($results as $r){` é somente para separar, não imprime nada na tela.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80937/discussion-between-leandro-marzullo-and-roberto-de-campos).